# How to copy one image and save as diff. name in document directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my document directory one image is their, with name Image1.

I want copy same image with name Image2 in document directory folder.

Please, suggest me how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer a following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath1= [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
NSString *imagePath2= [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image2.png"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:imagePath1 toPath:imagePath2 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get he data from first image and save the same data with another name like:

```
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0);

NSString *str=@"image2.png"

NSString *fileName = [[stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/"] stringByAppendingFormat:str];
NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two mathed of Fatch image and save image:
You fatch image that save in Document directory and then pass it to save image with different name:

```
-(UIImage *)loadImage:(NSString *)name
{
    NSString*   documentsDirectory=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];    
    UIImage *res = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

    return res;
}
-(void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString*   documentsDirectory=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil];
```

}